# Anyone seen this Duration format before?? /X//X//X/= 45 minutes /X/X/X = 30 minutes

Tags: datetime, duration

I'm working on a migration project and one part is appointments and they are using a format I've never seen before for the duration.

Before I create my own parser has anyone seen this, is it a standard?!

This is just a sample:

[image]

Comment: no standard I have ever seen, looks like a homage to Sumerian Cuneiform

Comment: At least the conversion is easy. duration = length * 5 minutes.